# Keep another div displayed block when I mouse over button but then close block element if I were to roll over it

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseleave

Any ideas would be great on how to tackle this one. Essentially it the same idea as a submenu.

```
 $(".button").on({
    mouseenter: function (e) {
       //display my other div as a block element and fade it in
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
 //if my mouse leaves that block element then fade it out.
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the other div to `display: none` in your CSS and use jQuery's [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) methods to toggle it on/off:

```
$(".button").on({
  mouseenter: function (e) {
    $(".other-div").fadeIn();
  },
  mouseleave: function () {
    $(".other-div").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vZLTm/1/).

Comment: I dont need the "othen-div" to fade out on ".button" mouseleave. I need to fade-out once it is visible and if were the mouse were to roll off it